# UNIFACE LDAP User authentication

Tags: ldap, using

Good morning,

we use LDAP within uniface to allow users to login to our system. When the username/password is correct, all is fine. But when an invalid password is used all we get is error code 49.
Is it possible to get a more meaningful error message. Something like: username/password is incorrect 
Password has expired 
or
username has been disabled.

My code is:

```
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------
; Initialise an ldap session (using PRIMARY DOMAIN CONTROLLER details)
; Get handle back to the session for use by subsequent calls
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------
activate "LDAP".LDAP_SSLINIT(v_handle,v_p_svr,v_p_port,v_ssl)
if($status != 0)        ;Failed 
    return(0)
endif

then

;---------------------------------------------------------
; Perform a BIND to the LDAP (thereby authenticating user)
;---------------------------------------------------------
activate "LDAP".LDAP_BIND_S(v_handle,v_dn,v_cred,v_method)
```

Uniface is a bit odd but I think the calls to ldap should be the same as in say Java.

Answer (score 0):

From the RFC4511, Appendix A.2 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#appendix-A.2) this means

> ```
> invalidCredentials (49)
> Indicates that the provided credentials (e.g., the user's name and password) are invalid.
> ```

The RFC4511 defines these standard error codes.

Depending on your specific LDAP server it may return additional (non-standard) error codes (like for example the Oracle OID: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28196_01/idmanage.1014/b15991/trblsht.htm#CHDFJBIG)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. Yes when the LDAP service returns 49 it does mean invalid credentials. But the following error codes should also be available:525 user not found
52e invalid credentials
I think these numeric codes get tagged onto the error 49 separated by a /. I'm thinking $status is not capable of handling this type of return value. If I set up the signature to return the value as the first parameter it come back as 0 or 1 to indicate success or failure.   So, still confused