# Uniface LDAPs authentication

Tags: ldap

I am trying to authenticate user logging with AD via LDAPs from an Uniface Application.
Current ASN settings:

```
  [PATHS]
    $LDP    LDP:host+389:DC=host,DC=co,DC=uk|username|password
  [DRIVER_SETTINGS]
    LDP = U1.0
    USYS$LDP_PARAMS = addbase:off
  [ENTITIES]
    *.LDAP      $LDP:*.*
    person.ldap=person@DC=host,DC=co,DC=uk
```

Now, I am able to retrieve the ldap details by initialising sAMAccountName.
Then trying to open ldap with user's DN and password, which is working fine.
But when I am trying the same thing using port 636, it does not work.

Does anyone know how to make Uniface interact with LDAP using 636 port?

Can I use wldap32.dll to achieve the same?

This post is in connection with [UNIFACE LDAP User authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35697148/3919328) query.

Thanks,
Dharmesh